# Spring Boot - java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am getting this error and I cannot solve this problem.

There were plenty of StackOverflow answers based on this topic, but neither one fits me.

The goal is to save `Todo` and afterwards save `TaskTodo`(connecting table of `Task` and `Todo`).

I tried to save and flush `Todo` and afterwards save `TaskTodo`, but it failed.

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

**ERROR:**

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`todo`.`task_todo`, CONSTRAINT `FK8dn0kderp1dame65xsokdaavj` FOREIGN KEY (`todo_id`) REFERENCES `todo` (`id`))

**Assignement - Parent abstract class:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Assignment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;

}
```

**Todo - Domain class:**

```
@Entity
public class Todo extends Assignment {

    private boolean isChecked;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "todo")
    Set<TaskTodo> taskTodoSet;
}
```

**Task - Domain class:**

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Assignment {

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
    public
    Set<TaskTodo> taskTodoSet;

    public Task() {}

    public Task(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }
}
```

**TaskTodo - domain class:**

```
@Entity
public class TaskTodo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    Task task;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "todo_id")
    Todo todo;

    public TaskTodo(Task task, Todo todo) {
        this.task = task;
        this.todo = todo;
    }
}
```

**Service function for saving Todo and TaskTodo:**

```
@Override
public void saveTodo(Todo todo, Long taskId) {
    Task task = getTaskById(taskId);
    todoRepository.saveAndFlush(todo);
    TaskTodo taskTodo = new TaskTodo(task, todo);
    taskTodoRepository.save(taskTodo);
}
```

Comment: `Todo` is created here: `todoRepository.saveAndFlush(todo);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what is the problem

Service function should look like this:

```
@Override
public void saveTodo(Todo todo, Long taskId) {
    Task task = getTaskById(taskId);
    todo = todoRepository.saveAndFlush(todo); // This line is changed
    TaskTodo taskTodo = new TaskTodo(task, todo);
    taskTodoRepository.save(taskTodo);
}
```

Reason is because `Todo` which was sent as parameter did not have id in itself and because of that there was an error.

When I put `todo = todoRepository.saveAndFlush(todo);`, `saveAndFlush` returned object which had id in itself. Because of that `TaskTodo` could be saved.

Comment: If this is to do with saveAndFlush, should the Service function has @Transactional annotation? That may help on your case without saveAndFlush?

Comment: Yes, it also works.
I figured out that even without `@Transactional` it is working.
The key was to put `todo = todoRepository.save(todo)`